# How can I add a sub svg tag in a raphael.js document?

Tags: javascript, svg, coffeescript, raphael

I'm using Raphael.js to produce an SVG drawing from Javascript (actually Coffeescript)

However, I'd like to be able to include subdrawings, automatically scaled, by putting them inside a second <svg> tag nested inside the first. Unfortunately the Raphael Paper object which allows me to add rects and paths etc. doesn't have an option for adding svgs.

I've tried to add the tag directly to the DOM in javascript with the following code :

```
res = document.createElement("svg")
res.setAttribute("x",x)
res.setAttribute("y",y)
res.setAttribute("width",width)
res.setAttribute("height",height)
res.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 100 100")
res.innerHTML = someInnerSVG
@paper.canvas.appendChild(res)
```

This seems to update the DOM as expected, adding my new SVG tag as a child of the main outer SVG. However, nothing in this inner actually appears on the screen. (My inner SVG path is scaled within 0 0 100 100 so is within the viewBox.)

The rest of the drawing in the outer SVG, as produced by Raphael, is visible. But nothing of the inner one is.

Should what I'm trying be possible? Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know Coffeescript, but it looks like you're not actually adding anything to the SVG element.

Comment: Isn't the "res.innerHTML=" setting the innerHTML for the new SVG element. While the @paper.canvas.appendChild then adds that to the outer SVG.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me that you're appending an empty SVG.  Try adding a `rect` or some other element to the inner SVG.

Comment: The "rect" is in the variable called someInnerSVG. (It's actually a bunch of paths)

Comment: Oh, alright.  I misread that.  Carry on!

Comment: this feels wrong. why not add the inner SVG shapes as separate shapes (you can group them together into a Raphael `set` to handle them uniformly)?

Comment: @EliranM. Can I use a viewBox to scale the inner drawings using Raphael set? I wanted to have standard component drawings and be able to place them within the main drawing with different transformations. The SVG tag's viewBox attribute seems to give me that, but I'm not seeing that Set does.

Answer (score 0):

You should place these sub elements into a Raphael set. From there, you will be able to apply transformations to the set. To transform the set, you would call the `transform()` method and use the `s` attribute:

```
set.transform('s[sx],[sy]');
```

Where `sx` is the horizontal scale amount and `sy` is the vertical scale amount. Remove the brackets when you insert the numbers.

Please refer to the documentation here: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform
The methods for elements apply to sets because sets are pseudo elements.